# What do I put under the door in the hotel?

Tags: undertale

What do I put under the door on the far right of the hotel in Undertale?I have tried the pancake thing shaped like Metatton's face but it didn't work.

Answer (score 7):

You can push a lot of things relative to the Annoying Dog, as it is suspected he is the character behind the door.

- A [Dog Residue](http://undertale.wikia.com/wiki/Dog_Residue). The person behind the door will just give two Dog Residues.
- A [Hot Dog](http://undertale.wikia.com/wiki/Hot_Dog...%3F). He will then give you a [Hush Puppy](http://undertale.wikia.com/wiki/Hush_Puppy).
- A Hot Cat. He won't really take it, but won't take anything in your inventory until you have that on you.
- A [Dog Salad](http://undertale.wikia.com/wiki/Dog_Salad). He won't give you anything for it.